# Creating User Form Submission - Only allow them to see their own submissions

Tags: forms

Current world I have a form that, when submitted, goes straight to the feedback which I then extract via .csv and do what I need to do with it.

Is there a way to have it set up so a User can fill out a form, submit it and always see their own submission whenever they go back on?

I need it to be set up so that users cannot see each other's form submissions, just their own, and it will need to be password protected so we know that only that person is accessing that list of submissions.

My initial idea was to have a password protected page for every user who would have their own password, then have the Form on there...but this would be a long way around when I need 100+ users submitting.

Cheers